# Bring Dropbox back to state on Day X?

Tags: dropbox

I turned on a laptop I hadn't turned on for a very long time, the dropbox folder on it started synching and...... my complete dropbox folder now has a gazillion files all with doublures, directories I deleted are back again and directories I renamed are now twice in there with both names. Including the files in them.

This will cost me a gazillion years to fix.

Is there an option to bring back the complete dropbox "state" as to be exactly on day X?

Comment: Although it falls out of the scope of the question, "bring back files' state as to be exactly on day X" is exactly what versioning systems such as git were created for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a batch restoration you can try out **[dropbox-restore](https://github.com/clark800/dropbox-restore) ***

You might have to do a bit of tinkering but it should work, incidentally there as an identical question on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18028642/297257)

You can go to [dropbox.com](https://www.dropbox.com) and follow these screenshots  to do each one manually
[image]

From your windows machine follow this 
[image]

Comment: You'd have to do this manually to every file. That's what the asker wants to avoid.

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy Thanks for pointing that out , will fix it

Comment: hmm yes... it would need file for file, but im not looking for older versions but I have 2 versions of the same files all over the place. But the tool looks good im going to give it a try.